# How to test OAuth2 login flow in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm new to web development and working on a Chrome extension which links up to your Google account using OAuth2. I'm using the following code to get an auth token for the current user:

```
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
      // do some stuff
    });
```

when I ran this code, it brought me to a login screen where I was able to log in with my Google account. Now when I call this, I get a valid token.

However, now I want to test the login flow as if I was a user logging in for the first time. From the Chrome docs, I tried running:

```
chrome.identity.clearAllCachedAuthTokens();
```

But that didn't seem to make a difference. I also tried running:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
    chrome.identity.removeCachedAuthToken({ token: token }, function (){})
```

And that didn't work either.  I also opened the extension in incognito mode but was still able to get the auth token instead of a login screen.

How can I "unauthenticate" or "log out" so that I can go through the auth flow again?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in a manual way by following these steps:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Click on "Third-party apps with account access"
3. Find my extension in the list and click "Remove access"